# Automatic login to multiple SSH root terminals

Tags: ssh, terminal

I am not sure if this is a security issue, or can be actually done.

I would like to be able to boot up my PC, maybe run a program that will open about 5 shells, each SSH'ing to my local machine but as root.

I would like to enter the root password only once for all 5 instances if possible.

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you thought about opening one shell, starting tmux or screen and creating 5 windows within that? Those will all be created with root as id.

Comment: use public/private keys, don't store plain text passwords. read into `ssh-keygen`

Comment: I didn't think that worked for logging in as root. I can login as my own user perfectly fine, but my PC isn't logged in as root, only shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to install sshpass

Then you create a little script called `openRootShells.sh` or something similar.

Insert the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s -p "Enter Password: " PASSWORD
konsole -e sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh root@localhost
konsole -e sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh root@localhost
konsole -e sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh root@localhost
konsole -e sshpass -p $PASSWORD ssh root@localhost
```

Make it executable and add the following to your `~/.xsession`

```
konsole -e ~/openRootShells.sh
```

Replace the konsole command with the right one for your desktop. Linke gnome-terminal oder xterm etc.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool, often used as sysadmin, called [clusterssh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/) to have command line interaction to many machines with the feature to write once by sending the typing to all of them (together with the possibility to write to the individual consoles.

You didn't mention the operating system of your pc. I use it in debian and there is a package for it. The command will be something like:

```
cssh `perl -E 'say "root\@localhost " x 5'`
```

Then you have to write only once the password (if you didn't setup pubkeys).